# Show that a function is surjective on a ball

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

> Let $B(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be the ball of radius 1 at the origin. Suppose $f:B(0,1)\to\mathbb R^n$ satisfies $f(0)=0$ and
> $$\forall x\neq y\in B(0,1), |f(x)-f(y)-(x-y)|<0.1|x-y|$$
> How can I show that for every $z\in B(0,0.4)$, there exists $x\in B(0,1)$ such that $f(x)=z$?

If $z\in B(0,0.4)$, then $|f(z)-z|\leq 0.04$ but I'm not sure how to show surjectivity from the conditions.

Comment: Do you know anything else about $f$? Is it continuous?

Comment: I think the conditions imply that $f$ is continuous. By the reverse triangle inequality, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 1.1|x-y|$ so it is lipschitz continuous with $K=1.1$.

Comment: @math34 I don't think that's correct. The reverse triangle inequality doesn't imply this. You can't just forget the modulus around it.

Comment: It's correct: \begin{align*}|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(y)-(x-y)+(x-y)|&\le|f(x)-f(y)-(x-y)|+|x-y|\\&<0.1|x-y|+|x-y|.\end{align*}

Comment: @Rino $|f(x)-f(y)| - |x-y|\leq |f(x) - f(y) - (x-y)| < 0.1|x-y|\implies |f(x)-f(y)| < 0.1|x-y| + |x-y| = 1.1|x-y|$.

Comment: What is the context of this question? It sounds like it needs a topological proof, something like the map $f$ is homotopic to the identity map and thus the fact that $z$ is in the interior of $f(\partial B(0,1))$ implies that it's in the image.

Comment: Another thing that crosses my mind when looking at such exercises is the numbers. Why 0.4? One could think that 0.45 or 0.3 also holds. It may only be important to have any number smaller than 0.5. Maybe you should think about this.

Comment: Intuitively to me, the function acts as identity on each neighbourhood of a point in the domain .Also it is injective.

Comment: The sphere of radius $0.9$ is mapped continuously and injectively into $B(0,1)\setminus B(0,0.8)$, which comfortably contains $B(0,0.4)$. @GregMartin's homotopy plan works straightforward from there

Answer (score -1):

*Hint*

As Op and @greg Martin  pointed out that $f$ is continuous.

Apply this property of continuous map ( hopefully you would have proved it )

> under a continuous map , inverse image of an open set is open.

Notice that $B(0,0.4)$ is open set
So, what will be $f^-1(B(0,0.4))$ ?

**Explanation**

> $f^{-1}(B(0,0.4))$ is an open subset of $B(0,1)$, let us denote it by $\beta$. Then given a point $z$ in $B(0,0.4)$ then
> $f^{-1}(z)=x\in \beta$. ( For some $x$)
> Thus, $f(x)=z$ and this is true for every $z\in B(0,0.4)$. And oviously $x$ will be in $B(0,1)$.

Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: $f^{-1}(B(0,0.4))$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$ so it is a union of open balls. Im not sure what i can say from here

Comment: $f^{-1}(B(0,0.4))$ is basically a open subset of $B(0,1)$. so , for every $z$ in $B(0,0.4)$ there is $x$ in $B(0,1)$ such that $f(x)=z$.

Comment: @OmPrakash I don't see where you get this surjectivity only from the fact that it's an open subset. Could you explain?

Comment: @Rino I gave explanation for it.

Comment: @OmPrakash Unless you're using arguments I don't know about, you are probably wrong. First of all, you don't seem to use openness in your argumentation. Second, you seem to have misunderstood the notation of a preimage as it's $ f^{-1}(Y)=\{x \in X : f(x) \in Y\}$. We don't yet have an inverse map as we're only now about to show surjectivity.